# Anyone? Induction cooktop and ferrous metal distances that Will NOT can NOT heat ferrous metal?

Tags: temperature, induction, gas, kitchen-safety

1,800w portable induction cooktop. I want to keep my ferrous metal propane tank FAR out of induction range in my tiny DIY RV can’t move stuff with out complete renovation. EMF at 1-ft was 30mG, and 7-ft was 2mG. Does that help identify a distance where induction CAN NOT WILL NOT generate any detectable heat in to ferrous metal (like propane tank)? Note, tanks in interior compartment gasket sealed door, floor ventilated to outside, gas lines exiting to exterior.

Comment: Propane tanks should be located OUTSIDE an RV, regardless of RV size.

Comment: Reply: Tanks enclosed in steel box 1/16 construction grounded to vehicle frame. But I don't want to count on this to diffuse heating. Reply: Not enough space under van to install exterior gas tank. Even if, still want portable tank for outdoor BBQ. Gas needed for electricity and heating. Gas used outside for generator. No gas cooking inside.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I think these sorts of electrical/equipment questions are off topic.  Mods can decide.

Comment: The way I interpret our rules, the question would not be directly closable. The OP did not ask "is this safe" (which would be indeed closable under a rule we instituted in the last few months) but "at which distance will metal not be heated" which is a question about a physical fact whose answer is independent of the context. We do have an "equipment" tag too, which would cover questions about the functioning of induction stoves.

Comment: @rumtscho - off topic = "Equipment or electrical safety (e.g. "Is this microwave still safe to use"): instead, please have a qualified professional inspect the appliance."  To me, this does not sound like a question on food or cooking.  Rather, and electrical/safety question.

Comment: @moscafj The literal question is, at what distance will the stove not induce any heat in a ferromagnetic material. The OP did not ask where to put a gas tank in order to be safe. The second is a safety question, the first is not.

Answer (score 1):

First off - you should be aware of the comment from Enercwal. Put your tank outside!

Could you not use some magnetic shielding to isolate the tank? A thin sheet of any ferro-magnetic material such as steel should work fairly well, certainly enough to drop any inductive heating in the tank.

EMF will drop on an inverse squared rule: 1/distance<sup>2</sup>, so at doubled distance you should have 1/(2<sup>2</sup>) = 1/4 the EMF. For example, at 1' you have EMF = 30 mG, at 2' (doubled distance) you should have 1/2<sup>2</sup> = 1/4 x 30 = 7.5 mG and at 4' you should have 1/4<sup>2</sup> = 1/16 x 30 = 1.9 mG etc. Note this doesn't take into account the natural magnetic field of the Earth nor from other electrical appliances.

At what point you won't get any detectable heating I don't know, but I suspect you don't need to be very far away. For some level of comparison, the Earth's magnetic field strength [is between 0.25 and 0.65 Gauss](https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/products/geomagnetism-frequently-asked-questions) (250 - 650 milliGauss (mG)), and you generally wouldn't expect to notice inductive heating from that.

The [literature suggests about 2-6 microTesla](https://%20https://doi.org/10.1046/j.1460-9592.2003.t01-1-00216.x) (1 Gauss = 10<sup>-4</sup> T or 100 microT) leakage of magnetic flux from induction stoves at a range of 20 cm and less than this at 50 cm. Since 30 mG = 3 microT, you are in the right range for your measurement. However, lots of every-day appliances put out much more magnetic flux (though typically not at the frequencies used for inductive heating) at these sorts of ranges - See table on pages 34-36 in [this PDF from the National Institute of Environmental and Health Sciences](https://www.niehs.nih.gov/health/materials/electric_and_magnetic_fields_associated_with_the_use_of_electric_power_questions_and_answers_english_508.pdf), which shows that every-day things like electric shavers and vacuum cleaners produce quite a bit more flux than this at 6" (~15 cm) You generally wouldn't consider that these would cause inductive heating in anything much around them, so you probably shouldn't be too concerned about the distance for your tank, once it is over a couple of feet (1' = ~30 cm) away.

If you wanted to test it empirically, you could make a rig to test how hot a sheet of metal of similar thickness to the tank gets at different distances from your stove. My bet is no effect over about 0.5 m (a bit less than 2') and possibly quite a bit closer.

However, take this advice with a grain of salt - I'm not an electrical engineer nor a gas-fitter, so: **consult an expert** and don't listen to advice from random strangers on the internet.

Comment: An induction cooktop heats because the magnetic field fluctuates. Essentially the magnetic field flip-flops back and forth. The earth's magnetic field is relatively stable, so it won't heat magnetic objects to any noticeable amount.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as MaxW points out, it's the *variation* in the magnetic field that induces a current. A static field won't cause heating, but the field in an induction cooker typically oscillates at about 20kHz. The field strength that you measured is almost certainly linked to either the earth's geomagnetic field or some DC current somewhere in the RV.

If you want to measure the relevant fields, you need a high-speed magnetic-field measurement device.

The magnetic field in an induction cooker is complicated, but in the worst case it can probably be approximated to a dipole configuration, which decreases as the square of the distance.

[Here is a relevant study](https://www.bag.admin.ch/dam/bag/de/dokumente/str/nis/faktenblaetter-emf/b-field-exposure.pdf.download.pdf/B-Field%20Exposure%20From%20Induction%20Cooking%20Appliances%20-%20ITIS%202007.pdf), made by the Swiss federal institute of technology. It's a well written report, that also explains how they measured the fields. They're mostly focused on the magnetic fields experienced by the cook, and find that the recommended fields *can* be exceeded - but only by being very close to the cooker. At 1cm the fields can exceed the regulation 6.25μT at the relevant frequencies (~20kHz, with some higher-level harmonics). When the distance increases to 5cm and 30cm, the field levels decrease a lot, as expected from the theory. (The relevant regulation, [EN50366](https://standards.iteh.ai/catalog/standards/clc/469399cb-5ecd-434c-aef7-fedeb57179d5/en-50366-2003), specifies measuring at 30cm from the device.)

In summary - As long as you don't have your propane tank touching the cooker, you're pretty safe. But you *really* should have it outside.